# Null variable not being detected

Tags: python

I'm confused at what I'm doing wrong. I have a variable that is sometimes null and I am trying to detect it but I cannot seem to raise a exception when it occurs.

```
  print(type(company_info['sub_industry']))
  if company_info['sub_industry'] is None:
    print(f"ERRROR {company} -  {company_info['sub_industry']}")
```

but even though the type of my data shows as null, the if statement isn't being executed:

```
<class '__main__.Null'>
<class '__main__.SAFE_STR'>
<class '__main__.SAFE_STR'>
<class '__main__.SAFE_STR'>
```

I checked and not sure where the problem is. The null item should trigger the print statement but it's not.

Comment: No, it shouldn't, you never check for some class named `Null`, instead you are checking for `None`

Comment: `None` is not the same thing as this `<class '__main__.Null'>`, whatever that might be.  Perhaps you need to explicitly test for that class - `if isinstance(X, Null):`

Comment: strange, I read on SO that None was like Null for python. I must have misread it.

Comment: `None` serves the same kind of *purpose*, but `type(None)` is quite distinct from whatever `__main__.Null` is.

Comment: @Lostsoul `None` does serve a similar purpose as `null` in other languages, but **there is no type named `Null` in Python as a built in** so that had to be some custom class, maybe from some library you are using.

Answer (score 0):

`None`is different from `<class '__main__.Null'>`:

```py
print(type(None))  # -> <class 'NoneType'>
```

Therefore, you should check like

```
if isinstance(company_info['sub_industry'], __main__.Null):
   print(...)
```